# Linq to Sql Chained Intersect

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable, intersect

I can't figure out why this isn't intersecting all of the items in the loop, just the last 2.  I think it has something to do with IQueryable

```
var outerquery = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Name = "Smith").Select(x => x.EmployeeID);

foreach(var name in nameList){
var innerQuery = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Name = name).Select(x => x.EmployeeID);
outerquery = outerquery.Intersect(innerQuery);
}

return outerquery.ToList();
```

EDIT - 
A more concrete example.  The table has approx 35 million records.

The table has ID, ConceptID, Word.  Words can have multiple ConceptIDs & there is 1 word per record.  I was to intersect a search string 'shoulder pain chronic' and get all the ConceptIDs that share those 3 words.  It should return:

```
Concept1234 - shoulder
Concept1234 - pain
Concept1234 - chronic
```

What I am getting (just the last 2):

```
Concept1234 - pain
Concept1234 - chronic
```

Doing an OR on 35 million records is rough even with this monster server I have & an intersect is the only way to do it in less than a second.

What I am trying to generate with LINQ to SQL (Entity Framework) is this -

```
SELECT ConceptID FROM WordTable WHERE Word = 'shoulder'
INTERSECT
SELECT ConceptID FROM WordTable WHERE Word = 'pain'
INTERSECT
SELECT ConceptID FROM WordTable WHERE Word = 'chronic'
```

Comment: Please provide more information: what do you expect and what did you get? Can you show us a concrete example?

Comment: Is it LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework? Two distinct things.

Answer (score 0):

You have `outerquery` inside the `foreach` loop which gets replaced in each iteration of the loop and you lose previous data.

Comment: But shouldn't intersecting on the outerquery then setting it to the outerquery again keep the changes?